# Integration help, hints or tips appreciated

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Can anyone help me integrate this integral? I'm stumped.
$$\int^y_0\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x(y-x)}}dx$$

Comment: Hint: $x(y-x)=\frac{1}{4}y^2-(x-\frac{1}{2}y)^2$.  Now make a trigonometric substitution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $x=y\sin^2\theta$. The integral will collapse.

Comment: How can we just arbitrarily choose what x can equal in terms of y?

Comment: We are integrating by substitution.  If you prefer, we are letting $\theta=\arcsin(\sqrt{x/y})$.

Comment: Ah, I get it. Thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome. It really does dramatically collapse!